# On premise SQL Server access with credentials from Azure AD

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, integrated-security

I am trying to access local resources (database) from Azure. I want to use permissions set on Azure AD user (the AD groups) to avoid the user from gaining too much access to database data.

So, I have a Azure AD User and a web app connected to local database (on premise) through a azure hybrid connection. When I access the database Azure uses a inbuilt IIS Account instead of the signed in user (the Azure user in synchronized with local domain AD User). Is this possible, and how to accomplish this ?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, it is not possible. Azure AD auth only supports Azure SQL(Paas).

Answer (score 1):

Passing Azure AD user credentials to on-prem SQL Server instance is not supported yet. Connecting to SQL Server running on an Azure VM is not supported using an Azure.

Active Directory account. Use a domain Active Directory account instead. However, It is you can pass Azure SQL database then it is possible to configure Azure SQL database with Azure AD authentication.

Note here gives more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure